# Two ClassLoaders; One classloader needs to cast-down an Object but other classloader don't let it

Tags: java, reflection, casting, classloader

I'm trying to reference an object loaded via a classloader in a class that is loaded by another classloader. I need to do a cast-down that object to access some methods. I need a way to do this casting avoiding the other classloader. 
I *know* that we can't cast classes of differnt classloaders, and that is *not* what I need here. I need to do the casting in the same classloader avoiding the other classloader which has loaded the same class. It turned out really difficult.

Here's a little context. As you see in the classes below, I receive an object at MyClass.configure() method via the method ComponentResolver.lookup() which is an instance of Mojo but casted to Object.

Unfortunately, `Mojo mojo = clazz.cast(o)` (in MyClass below) fails with a compilation error, saying the returned type of clazz.cast is Object. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this? May be via the same Class#cast method or via reflection? I'm not much familiar with reflection though!

```
//This is loaded by, say ClassLoader X
public class ComponentResolver {
    public Object lookup(String role) {

        //do something
        return component;     //component is an instance of Mojo interface.
    }
}
```

Here's MyClass that where I invoke the lookup method.

```
//This class including Mojo in this context is loaded by, say ClassLoader Y
public class MyClass {
    public void configure() {
        Object o = componentResolver.lookup("componentName");

//      Mojo mojo = (Mojo) o;  //causes classcastexception (obviously.)

        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.Mojo", false,
                o.getClassLoader()   );

        Mojo mojo = clazz.cast(o);
    //Causes compiler errors because the returned object is of type Object. 
    //ie incompatible types Required:Mojo, Found:Object

       // Mojo mojo = (Mojo) clazz.cast(o); //again classcastexception.

        mojo.execute();
       }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mojo` class loaded by your classloader and the `Mojo` class loaded by the other classloader are completely different classes as far as the JVM is concerned.

Some options:

- Do whatever you need to in terms of invoking methods etc via reflection
- Create a new `Mojo` based on the existing one via reflection, then using that (it depends what `Mojo` is really doing)
- Change your classloader hierarchy so that one classloader delegates to another one, so that you can just cast.

You're in a fundamentally nasty position, and there are no *easy* workarounds that I'm aware of. If you can *possibly* fix the classloader hierarchy, it'll make your life a *lot* easier. Just having `Mojo` in a classloader which both of the other classloaders have as their parent would be enough.

Comment: second and third options are not possible in my case. For third, changing the classloaders are off-limits to this code I'm working on. So, it turned out that Reflection is the way to go. Would you mind on adding an example to do the same via reflection to your answer?

Comment: @ravana: You won't be able to *cast* it with reflection - you'll have to invoke every method with reflection, the same as any other use of invoking methods by reflection - there are loads of examples on the web. If you need to do anything non-trivial, it's going to get horribly messy :(

Comment: I see. It will be a little messy then. My issue with reflection is that since the object is casted to Object class, how to invoke the method in Mojo. Or do I need not to worry about it? I'm new to reflection!

Comment: @ravana: You'd need to call `o.getClass().getMethod()` to get the method, then invoke that etc. Read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html to get started.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My previous question wasn't exactly that. But I'll start reading the given tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It is weird think and adds a lot of limitations of using such classes.

If your second class-loader loads only Mojo and all other fields' types loaded by first classloader you can create one more object of class loaded by second classloader and copy all fields' values to it.

```
@NotNull
public static <T> T copy(@NotNull Class<T> targetClass,
                         @NotNull Object original) throws ReflectionException {
  try {
    final T other = createHierarchical(targetClass);
    Class<?> aClass = ruleClass;
    Class<?> oClass = original.getClass();
    while (aClass != null && oClass != null) {
      for (Field otherField : aClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (Modifier.isStatic(otherField.getModifiers()))
          continue;
        final Field originalField = oClass.getDeclaredField(otherField.getName());
        Object value = getFieldValue(original, originalField);
        final Class<?> otherFieldType = otherField.getType();
        if (!otherFieldType.isPrimitive() && value != null 
            && !otherFieldType.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())) {
          value = copy(otherFieldType, value);
        }
        hackField(other, otherField, value);
      }
      aClass = aClass.getSuperclass();
      oClass = oClass.getSuperclass();
    }
    if (aClass != null || oClass != null)
      throw new ReflectionException("Class has not identical hierarchy");
    return other;
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    throw new ReflectionException(e);
  }
}
```

In this code:
  hackField - set a value to field of any kind, even if it is not accesable or final;
  getFieldValue - get value of field;
  createHierarchical - creates object throughtclass using object serialization instantination method.

But as I said before this method works only if your classes are very simple. The should not have fields of types which were loaded by another classloader, your should not have complex logic based of fileds values in constructor, and you should understand that new object will contains all fields' reference to already existing objects.